Send email in Laravel 11
I would like to send an email using Laravel, but I am getting an error, I am sending it this way:
UsersController.php
....
$user_created = (new UserCreated($user))                
                ->onQueue('emails')->afterCommit();

            Mail::to($user->email)
                ->queue($user_created);
.....

This is the mailable: UserCreated.php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\Listing;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Address;

class UserCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(protected User $user) {}

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
      

        return new Content(
            markdown: 'emails.users.created',
            with: [....]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            from: new Address(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name')),
            subject: 'test'          
        );
    }
    
}

I noticed the email is not being sent to the user's email address, it is sent to the email address that is in my .env file:
MAIL_TO_ADDRESS=admin@myweb.com,
what can I do?

Move/remove the onQueue and afterCommit from the UserCreated call and to the Mail call. It may be trying to queue-send the email before the Mailto

I made the changes, it is still not working, so weird,I even removed the MAIL_TO_ADDRESS, and now is trying to send it to hello@example.com

After changes did you restart your queue?
php artisan queue:restart

I removed completely the queue part, I am sending the email without any queues, so weird

I found the reason,a developer added this to the mail config file
'to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_TO_NAME', 'Name'),
    ]

Because in the beginning the website was not supposed to send emails to users, only one person would be notified. this was overwritten the Mail::to($user->email)
Now everything works fine

If MAIL_TO_ADDRESS is set in env, Laravel will override the recipient address and send all emails to this address. You can keep MAIL_TO_ADDRESS for your development environment and for testing but in production remove it and after that run the following commands to make sure the changes work:
php artisan config:cache
php artisan queue:restart --queue=queue_name


The MAIL_TO_ADDRESS should be MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS, as far as I understand you want to send mail from admin@myweb.com.

No, I want send the email to user's email address, the destination

You need to specify proper MAIL_HOST in your mail config file
'smtp' => [
      'transport' => 'smtp',
      'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
      'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
      'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
      'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
      'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
      'timeout' => null,
 ],


In my local environment the MAIL_HOST is set to sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io and in production is set to smtp.postmarkapp.com, in both cases are failing, so weird

If configurations and code are correct then check spam inbox. And can you share more like error log?
